# Primes in C: RunTime Error

Tags: c, function, loops, primes

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isPrime(int n){
    int ndiv = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i=i+1){
        if(n%i == 0){
            ndiv = ndiv+1;
        }
    }

    if(ndiv == 2){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int nextPrime(int n){}

int main(){
    int a = isPrime(7);
    printf(a);
    //printf(isPrime(4));

}
```

This code gives me a run time error, I think there's a problem here with the way I deal with data types while using a functions and the printf command, but I can't really figure it out. Help!

Comment: `printf(a);` - this is not how you use `printf`

Comment: is it always supposed to be "%d",%a ?

Comment: [Read some `printf` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: When in doubt - read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `f` in `printf` stands for "format". You need to supply a format string for printing: `printf("%d\n", a)`
- Your `isPrime` is inefficient: you do not need to attempt dividing all the way up to the number itself. You could stop once you reach the square root of the number
- Moreover, you could exit the loop early once you see that the number is *not* prime.

Once you fix these errors, your program would start running and producing the output that you expect.

Comment: More efficient if you start by checking if n%2==0. then if not loop `for ( i=3; i <= root; i+=2)` Note that this is still not the most efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example of how to use `printf`. You can find more **format specifiers** [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 97;
    int b = 98;
    char hello[6] = "world";
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    printf("%s\n", hello);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your method of printing a variable is wrong. Here's the right one.

```
int main(){
  int a = isPrime(7);
  printf("%d",a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no C/C++ expert, but try

```
printf("%d", a);
```

%d is a format placeholder expecting an integer number, essentially.

That looks like an interesting isPrime function. Not very efficient at all, but different from what I have seen in the past. You can also loop over all the numbers between 1 and n, and just return false (or 0) if you find any that divise n. Or look up more efficient algorithms.